# Ignore Mercurial sub directories

Tags: java, maven, mercurial, ignore, hgignore

I have a directory with my `Maven` projects in it. It looks like this:

```
.hg
.idea
parentProject
project1
   .idea
   docs
   src
   target   
   pom.xml 
project2
   .idea
   docs
   src
   target 
   pom.xml
target
pom.xml
.hgignore
```

I want to ignore the `.idea` and `target` directories in all my project. I have included the `.idea` and `target` directories into `.hgignore` but it only ignores those directories in the which `.hgignore` file is. This means that only in root directory `.idea` and `target` is ignored.

If I add `.hgignore` file in all sub projects this does not changes anything files are still not ignored.

My ignore list looks like this:

```
build
dist
target
faces-config.NavData
.idea
.iml
```

How should I specify in the `.hgignore` to get the `.idea` and `target` ignored from everywhere?

Comment: Note that there's [a specific bug in IntelliJ about this](http://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/IDEA-65229).

Comment: I am not using intellij to commit or push, I am just coding with it, but commiting and pushing through command line.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

try [hgignore with regex](http://linux.die.net/man/5/hgignore)

```
syntax: regexp
^\.idea$
^target$
```

Comment: Not working, if I add these into .hgignore and run hg st I still see a lot of files which are in .idea directory.

Comment: you need `hg forget` to remove files added by mistake

Comment: Nope. Your regexp would also match `myDir/abacadabratarget/` which is clearly **not** what you want. The regexp to ignore the target directory and everything below it would be something like `^target/.*$'` or I guess `^target/` would suffice.

Comment: Thanks for bring that up, ^target$ is fine, it will pruning the directory and thus ignoring its contents, ref to http://mercurial.selenic.com/wiki/.hgignore

Answer (score 0):

How about something like `**/.idea` and `**/target`? Check out the [possible patterns here](http://www.selenic.com/mercurial/hg.1.html#patterns).

Comment: If I do like this: **/.idea it gives me: invalid pattern (relre): **/.idea. I have also tried **.idea, the same invalid pattern.

Comment: Does it works for the target directories? Possibly you have to escape the `.` in the beginning like this: `**/\.idea`

Comment: With a target it seems to be working like this: target/ but with .idea I can't get it working. I tried this: **/\.idea the same invalid pattern

Comment: `**/\.idea` definitely makes no sense.  `**` is glob syntax and `.` is only a special character in regex syntax.

Comment: Yes, @Ry4an is right, I shouldn't comment before the first cup of coffee :-)

Answer (score 0):

You should **not** need to explicitly ignore `target` directory.

This problem will come if you have added it by mistake to Mercurial. Let's say you have done the following:

1. Created a project and compiled a few times (hence `target` directory
   exist)
2. Decided to add source control to the project so you've
   initialized a Mercurial repository and executed `hg add` command
   (either implicitly or explicitly from the IDE). Bam! You have now
   told Mercurial that `target` is a directory that should be included.

Trust me. I've been there !

To fix: Do the following from the command line:

```
hg forget target
```

When it comes to `.idea` directory I would think there's no other way than to use the `.hgignore` file but I'm puzzled why Intellij IDE doesn't add this automatically. (not a Intellij IDE user myself). That is the real question to ask.

Comment: Actually, [the IntelliJ doc](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/managing-projects-under-version-control.html) suggests *including* rather than ignoring `.idea` folder, excepting the `workspace.xml` and `tasks.xml` files.